# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\app\management\config.php on line 37?

Tags: parsing, syntax, line

So I made my own habbo retro, and everything was done. But when I went to check it out, I got this error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\app\management\config.php on line 37
I checked it out, and this is what I have

/*
*
*   Hotel management  - All URLs do not end with an "/"
*
*/

$_CONFIG['hotel']['name'] = 'Habbeen'; // Your Hotel's Name

$_CONFIG['hotel']['desc'] = 'If you're bored, come here to feed your hunger.'; //Hotel's description 
 That is line 37 above this sentence. Why is that error coming up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a habbo retro is but your problem is because of the apostrophe in the "you're", you should escape it like this:" "you\'re"

Comment: Nope. Still getting this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\app\management\config.php on line 37

Comment: $_CONFIG['hotel']['desc'] = 'If you\'re bored, come here to feed your hunger.'; //Hotel's description